# Amazon AWS S3 to Force Stream(showing up) mp4 and png File instead of Download It using Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 to put the mp4 and png file on server then allow our app user to share this file url to your friend. When any other user click on file url the file is downloaded directly but I want showing up this file on browser instead of download.
Can any one suggest me which permission is needed.
I have use followign for upload mp4 and png file.

```
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                objectMetadata.setContentType("video/mp4");
                PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(
                        Constants.BUCKET_NAME.toLowerCase(Locale.US),   bucketPath +"MyVideo.mp4" , mFile)
                        .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
                putObjectRequest.setMetadata(objectMetadata);
                mUpload = getTransferManager().upload(putObjectRequest);
```

Comment: Are you referring to <uses-permission> tag in android manifest?

Comment: video/mp4 is the correct content type. In theory it should be played in browser, unless the device has customization on mime type handling. Would you please check the content type of the uploaded video is indeed video/mp4 in the S3 console?

Comment: Ok, I will check it on S3 console.